# How to install Theano library using sageMath locally?

Tags: python, machine-learning, theano, sage

I want to know steps of installing Theano library using SageMath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just install theano using pip by running this in the terminal.

```
$ sage -pip install theano
```

Next time you run Sage, theano is available.

```
sage: from theano import *
sage: import theano.tensor as T
sage: from theano import function
sage: x = T.dscalar('x')
sage: y = T.dscalar('y')
sage: z = x + y
sage: f = function([x, y], z)
sage: f(2, 3)
array(5.0)
sage: numpy.allclose(f(16.3, 12.1), 28.4)
True
sage: type(x)
<class 'theano.tensor.var.TensorVariable'>
```